Index Match Formula
I have a Spreadsheet with Columns A through J that contains Data. There are 560 Rows. I have three cells to input Lookup Data in K2,L2,M2. My Formula is in Cell N1.
I have the following Formula:
=INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(1, ($K$2=E2:E562)*($L$2=F2:F562)*($M$2=G2:G562),0),1)

It does not find anything below Rows 555.I have tried to make all References Absolute, I did have the INDEX ($C$2:$C$560) ,it makes no difference. The Formula finds everything from Row 2 to 555.
I need to find the Data in Column C with matching criteria in E,F,G to the Formula, Referencing K2,L2,M2

If you have 560 rows then why not use in this way: =INDEX(C$2:C$562, MATCH(1, ($K2=E$2:E$562)*($L2=F$2:F$562)*($M2=G$2:G$562),0))

Because there are no exact matches. reasons can be e.g. bad date format, strings with leading/trailing spaces or something else. Check the formula with Formula evaluation

I use more Rows because of Adding more Data at the end, if I go beyond the 560, I will change the Formula to look a few Rows beyond. But, any case, even if I put the Exact Row Count, it still does not work. All of the Look Up Cells are Numbers Types and the 3 Columns E, F, G are Numbers Types as well.

Mayukh Bhattacharya, the Formula Evaluation does nothing except say "False" and then "0", even on Data that it finds.

If you are sure that you will be having more rows, then you can use structured references it will help more instead of using blank ranges, which slows down the working capacity of excel. also which i thought that your formula wasnt working because you have not used absolute ranges. not sure whether there white spaces or leading spaces or any non printable characters

Could you enter =($K$2=E2:E562)*($L$2=F2:F562)*($M$2=G2:G562), for example in P2 and see what you get for rows 555-560 for the values you're expecting a match? If that does not give a clue, could post sample data in rows 555-560 (along with the criteria)?

Then of course reduce the conditions one by one and see which equal condition is failing and why.

=INDEX($C2:$C562, MATCH(1, MMULT(($K$2=E2:E562)*($L$2=F2:F562)*($M$2=G2:G562),1),0),1)


I tried the MMULT, that only gave me a 0.

Okay, I had the Three Data Columns set Data Type Number - No Decimals. I assumed that all of the Rows for those Columns were of the same Data Type. The Columns were set to Center. I Cleared the Format on the troubled Rows, they were Set Like Text, I tried to Re-Format them as a Number and they would not, no matter what I did. I Deleted those Rows and Re-Entered them making sure they were of Data Type Number, No Decimals, they work now. Having the Columns set to Center blinded what was going. Thank you to all who have taken the time and effort for trying to help me in this issue, maybe some day I can return the favor! Have a Great Week!!

if the result was from a formula and was recognised as text, then add a last operation of *1 (multiply by 1) which will trigger the number recognition.
